# Unable to Set dynamic CCAddress in HTML email/VF email template

Tags: email-template

I am trying to add `{!contact.owner}` in ccAddress while sending email. Email alert gets triggered on workflow. I could not find any ccAddress in HTML email and also in VF email template.

Is it possible to achieve or any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this one myself the other day. The "Selected Recipients" are the addresses that end up in the "To" field. The "Additional Addresses" are used for the cc list - problem is, you can only provide plain text addresses here.

You'll have to write code to seperate the addresses & use field info for the cc list.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a trigger and calling a method in apex class. That method is sending email using `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage`.